# ST32F4 interrupt handler not getting called

Tags: stm32, iar

Disassembly shows that MCU gets stuck at NMI_Handler so that means that interrupt is working.

Why isn't the interrupt handler getting called ?

My code-

```
    #include <intrinsics.h>
#include <stm32f4xx.h>


 void TIM6_DAC_IRQHandler(void)
{
  TIM6->SR = 0;
   GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<7);
   GPIOA->ODR |= (1<<7);

}


void TIM6Config (void)
{
 
    /************** STEPS TO FOLLOW *****************
    1. Enable Timer clock
    2. Set the prescalar and the ARR
    3. Enable the Timer, and wait for the update Flag to set
    ************************************************/

// 1. Enable Timer clock
    RCC->APB1ENR |= (1<<4);  // Enable the timer6 clock
    
// 2. Set the prescalar and the ARR
    TIM6->PSC = 90;  
    TIM6->DIER |= 1;
// 3. Enable the Timer, and wait for the update Flag to set
    TIM6->CR1 |= (1<<0); // Enable the Counter
    while (!(TIM6->SR & (1<<0)));  // UIF: Update interrupt flag..  This bit is set by hardware when the registers are updated
        NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);
        
}




void GPIOConfig (void)
{

    /************** STEPS TO FOLLOW *****************
    1. Enable GPIOA clock
    2. Set the PIN PA5 as output
    3. Configure the output mode
    ************************************************/

    // 1. Enable GPIOA clock
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= (1<<0);  // Enable the GPIOA clock
    
    // 2. Set the PIN PA5 as output
    GPIOA->MODER |= (1<<14);  // pin PA5(bits 11:10) as Output (01)
    
    // 3. Configure the output mode
    GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~(1<<7);  // bit 5=0 --> Output push pull
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= (1<<15);  // Pin PA5 (bits 11:10) as Fast Speed (1:0)
    GPIOA->PUPDR &= ~((1<<14) | (1<<15));  // Pin PA5 (bits 11:10) are 0:0 --> no pull up or pulldown
}

    


int main (void)
{
    
    TIM6Config ();
    GPIOConfig ();
       

    while (1)
    {

    }
    
}
```

Disassembly of vector table

```
__vector_table:
    0x8000000: 0x20002000     ANDCS     R2, R0, R0
    0x8000004: 0x08000165     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R2, R5, R6, R8}
    0x8000008: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x800000c: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x8000010: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x8000014: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x8000018: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x800001c: 0x00000000     ANDEQ     R0, R0, R0
    0x8000020: 0x00000000     ANDEQ     R0, R0, R0
    0x8000024: 0x00000000     ANDEQ     R0, R0, R0
    0x8000028: 0x00000000     ANDEQ     R0, R0, R0
    0x800002c: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x8000030: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x8000034: 0x00000000     ANDEQ     R0, R0, R0
    0x8000038: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
    0x800003c: 0x0800011b     STMDAEQ   R0, {R0, R1, R3, R4, R8}
NVIC_EnableIRQ:
    0x8000040: 0xf0102201     DC32      0xf0102201 (-267378175)
    0x8000044: 0x408a011f     ADDMI     R0, R10, PC, LSL R1
    0x8000048: 0xb240491d     SUBLT     R4, R0, #475136         ; 0x74000
    0x800004c: 0xf8410940     SRSDA     SP, #0
    0x8000050: 0x47702020     LDRBMI    R2, [R0, -R0, LSR #32]!
```

Comment: You need to figure out where the NMI is coming from, or if that is being used as a filler vector in boilerplate code you haven't shown for non-existent handlers.  Do you get the NMI even if you do not try to enable or trigger the intended interrupt?  Where did your code come from?  Try examples *unmodified* first.

Comment: @ChrisStratton .If I don't enable interrupt in NVIC(NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIM6_DAC_IRQn);) then I don't get NMI.I wrote this code my self .

Comment: I don't see anything referencing `TIM6_DAC_Handler()`.  How does the code know to vector to this function?

Comment: @Aaron *hopefully* the name matches and thus overrides a *weak symbol* in a vector table given in boilerplate startup code.  Of course that's not included in the post, so it could be something as trivial as a minor name mixup.  I'd like to know if the weak default symbols all point to the same routine which is the NMI handler...

Comment: @jurgis1991 please do a symbolic dump of the vector table portion of the elf so that we can see the name of your custom handler appearing at the correct point in the vector table.  Use the programmer's manual to figure out which vector that should be.  State exactly which STM32 you are using, as well.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I know that. It's a question designed to make the OP research it to make sure.  As you say "*hopefully*", but only they can tell for sure.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong code.I have edited the question with the correct handler.@ChrisStratton. @Aaron

Comment: @ChrisStratton.The MCU is STM32F407 .I am using the standard libraries provided by ST.

Comment: Again, please provide a symbolic disassembly of the relevant portion of the vector table, eg, whatever your project puts at 0x08000000 but clipped to the part that actually is relevant for this interrupt.

Comment: I have added vector table to the qestion.@ChrisStratton

Comment: There's a problem with your vector table - it's much too short. What you've shown there is only the 1st 16 entries, which correspond to the initial stack value, reset vector, NMI, HardFault, ... etc ... Systick. These are the Core interrupt vectors. You're missing the vectors for all the other interrupts from the peripherals which come thru the NVIC. My best guess is that you've forgotten to include one of the (typically assembler) startup source code files in your project.

Comment: Have you ruled out C++ name mangling?

Comment: As brhans said this vector table is far too short, and some of the values appearing in it are utterly illegal as code addresses.  Looks like some sort of project setup / linking issue where the full vector table of default weak symbols isn't getting used.  Try backing up to some known good example code, verifying that builds a proper vector table and then insert a minimal version of your code into that.  Even simply put in the ISR, without anything that would activate the interrupt, and verify it's ending up in the image at the correct place in the vector table.